# fsharp get nth element from a list

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

This is a really easy question but I'm just not familiar with pattern matching and f# syntax.

I'm trying to write a function that takes an int and an a' list, and return the nth element of type a'. I'm thinking of something like this:

```
let rec getn n xs=
  match n with
  0 -> {split xs into x::xs and then return x}
  _ -> {split xs into x::xs and call getn with n-1, xs}
```

Can someone help me with the syntax please? 
Thanks

Comment: Why not use `List.nth?`

Comment: This is just a practice. I'm trapped in general about how to pattern match when I have more than one parameters.

Comment: Well here is the official implementation of `nth`: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs#L59

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let rec getn n xs =
    match n, xs with
      | 0, (x::_)   -> x
      | _, (_::xs') -> getn (n - 1) xs'
      | _, []       -> invalidArg "n" "n is too large"
```

I think `if` would be clearer than `match` here though:

```
let rec getn n xs =
    if List.isEmpty xs then invalidArg "n" "n is too large"
    let x::xs' = xs in if n = 0 then x else getn (n - 1) xs'
```

Answer (score 2):

list supports index, [i]

```
let alist = [1..9] 
let n = 5

alist.[n-1] |> Console.Write
```

[image]